# The value in the array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to retrieve or check whether the "ket_upload" key contains "cash" or "credit" values. Do you have any suggestions?

The data is like this :

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [kd_upber] => 54 
        [kd_p] => 35 
        [kd_r] => 16 
        [harga] => 128000000 
        [type] => 64 Plus 
        [lokasi] => Ds. PENTADIO BARAT, KEC. TELAGA BIRU 
        [blok] => D 
        [no_rumah] => 1 
        [ket_upload] => credit 
        [ktp] => NULL 
        [npwp] => NULL 
        [kk] => NULL
        [skbm] => NULL 
        [buku_nikah] => NULL 
        [kpr] => NULL 
        [tanggal] => 2020-12-31 : 08:19:39
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [kd_upber] => 55 
        [kd_p] => 35 
        [kd_r] => 17 
        [harga] => 150000000 
        [type] => 64 Plus 
        [lokasi] => Ds. PENTADIO BARAT, KEC. TELAGA BIRU 
        [blok] => E 
        [no_rumah] => 1 
        [ket_upload] => cash 
        [ktp] => NULL 
        [npwp] => NULL 
        [kk] => NULL 
        [skbm] => NULL 
        [buku_nikah] => NULL 
        [kpr] => NULL 
        [tanggal] => 2020-12-31 : 08:21:47 
    )
)
```

Comment: What kind of an array is this?

Comment: please be clear in title of question, the main question and give all clear problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a suggestion maybe can try this too

```
foreach($array as $row){
  if($row['ket_upload'] == 'credit' || $row['ket_upload'] == 'cash'){
     #code ...
  }
}
```

Hope it help ya! also please let me know if there is any error or wrong with my code.

Comment: I'm glad that it can help you!

Comment: I'm sorry .. your answer is correct and I've tried it successfully, but I want to find a specific value for example "cash" in the array of keys "ket_upload" but not using a loop. I want to point directly can I?

Comment: Sure, just go ahead and try it. haha

Comment: I mean, how can I access those values ​​without foreach?

Comment: hmm, if I did not get it wrong you can do it that way too but u need to know the key for the row you want to check or if that any other way that to achieve that. Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15093859/get-element-at-n-position-in-an-array-without-loop can help you.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should using `function` somethings like that ;

```
function check_has ( $array ) {    
    if( is_array ( $array ) ) { 
        foreach( $array as $key => $value  ) {
        if ($key ==  'ket_upload' and ($value == 'credit' or $value == 'cash')){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}`
```